# What is difference between sales_order_payment_refund and sales_order_creditmemo_refund

Tags: php, magento, events, magento-1.9, orders

What is difference between `sales_order_payment_refund` and `sales_order_creditmemo_refund` events in **Magento CE 1.9** and when these events are dispatched?
As refund information is not mentioned in credit memo email,
I am working on sending custom email notification to customer whenever refund will be made for an order.
Thanks in advance for any help.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two events are very close to each other, and can be used almost interchangeably:

[`sales_order_payment_refund`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/d6654602d3f3b612da41d576ae65ebc4241abf25/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php#L730) is called first, as long as the payment can be refunded (i.e. hasn't already been refunded already). It returns with the Payment and Creditmemo objects in the event data.

[`sales_order_creditmemo_refund`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/d6654602d3f3b612da41d576ae65ebc4241abf25/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Creditmemo.php#L461) is called almost immediately after, it only returns the Creditmemo object.

Comment: which can be most suitable event to handle for my flow stated in question?

Comment: Probably `sales_order_payment_refund` - it is triggered on a refund and passes more event data